# Issues in `density.ppp` comparing results for `kernel = "gaussian"` and Gaussian kernel rebuild by user

Tags: r, kernel-density, spatstat

I am currently working intensively with the [`density.ppp`](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/blob/master/R/density.ppp.R) function, calling it with different kernel functions of my own design.
For my project I also need to 'rebuild' the kernel functions already available, such as `"gaussian"` and `"quartic"` kernel.

Therefore, I called `density.ppp` with `kernel = "gaussian"` and compared its outcome with the results from calling `density.ppp` with my own kernel function which reproduces a Gaussian kernel.

I found that for the Gaussian kernel this behaves much differently from doing the same thing for other built-in kernels, e.g. `kernel = "quartic"`.

I understand that this is because the kernel values are calculated differently conditional on the kernel that is used. For all kernels but the `"gaussian"`-one `evaluate2Dkernel` is called. The kernel value computations for `kernel = "gaussian"` on the other hand are hard-coded into `densitypointsEngine` and `second.moment.engine`.

I had two main issues with this:

1. If one uses `at = "points"` and `leaveoneout = FALSE`,

   ```
   # ----- contribution from point itself ----------------
   if(!leaveoneout) {
   # add contribution from point itself
   self <- const
   if(!is.null(weights))
     self <- self * weights
   result <- result + self
   ```

   }

   is executed.

   Prior to that, `const` is set. For all kernels but the
   `"gaussian"`-one, we have `const <- 1/sigma^2`. For `kernel = "gaussian"`, `const` is
   afterwards set to `const <- const/(2*pi)` in order to use it as the
   constant before the exponntial function in the hard-coded kernel
   value computation:

   ```
   # constant factor in density computations
   if(is.null(varcov)) {
     const <- 1/sigma^2 
   } else {
     detSigma <- det(varcov)
     Sinv <- solve(varcov)
     const <- 1/sqrt(detSigma)
   }
   if(isgauss) {
     # absorb leading constant in Gaussian density
     const <- const/(2 * pi)
   }
   ```

   I think this is incorrect, because it should always add `1/sigma^2` for the point that is not left out, but if `kernel = "gaussian"` it adds `1/2*pi*(sigma^2)`. Am I right about this?
2. Somehow, I temporarily was convinced that my results for `kernel = "gaussian"` vs. my Gaussian-kernel-rebuild also differed because in [`second.moment.engine`](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat/src/R/Kmeasure.R) one finds

   ```
   # set up kernel
   xcol.ker <- xstep * c(0:(nc-1),-(nc:1))
   yrow.ker <- ystep * c(0:(nr-1),-(nr:1))
   kerpixarea <- xstep * ystep
   if(identical(kernel, "gaussian")) {
     if(!is.null(sigma)) {
       densX.ker <- dnorm(xcol.ker, sd=sigma)
       densY.ker <- dnorm(yrow.ker, sd=sigma)
       #' WAS:  Kern <- outer(densY.ker, densX.ker, "*") * kerpixarea
       Kern <- outer(densY.ker, densX.ker, "*")
       Kern <- Kern/sum(Kern)
     } else if(!is.null(varcov)) {
       ## anisotropic kernel
       detSigma <- det(varcov)
       Sinv <- solve(varcov)
       halfSinv <- Sinv/2
       constker <- kerpixarea/(2 * pi * sqrt(detSigma))
       xsq <- matrix((xcol.ker^2)[col(Ypad)], ncol=2*nc, nrow=2*nr)
       ysq <- matrix((yrow.ker^2)[row(Ypad)], ncol=2*nc, nrow=2*nr)
       xy <- outer(yrow.ker, xcol.ker, "*")
       Kern <- constker * exp(-(xsq * halfSinv[1,1]
                                + xy * (halfSinv[1,2]+halfSinv[2,1])
                                + ysq * halfSinv[2,2]))
       Kern <- Kern/sum(Kern)
     } else 
       stop("Must specify either sigma or varcov")
   } else {
     ## non-Gaussian kernel
     ## evaluate kernel at array of points
     xker <- as.vector(xcol.ker[col(Ypad)])
     yker <- as.vector(yrow.ker[row(Ypad)])
     Kern <- evaluate2Dkernel(kernel, xker, yker,
                              sigma=sigma, varcov=varcov, ...) * kerpixarea
     Kern <- matrix(Kern, ncol=2*nc, nrow=2*nr)
     Kern <- Kern/sum(Kern)
   }
   ```

   The multiplication with `kerpixarea` is only done if the kernel is not `"gaussian"`. But after some testing I discovered that due to the `Kern <- Kern / sum(Kern)` line it does not matter if this multiplication is done.

   But then I wonder why it is still there? The

   `#' WAS:  Kern <- outer(densY.ker, densX.ker, "*") * kerpixarea`

   comment means that for `kernel = "gaussian"` there was a change made to avoid this unneccessary calculation, right? Why is it still there for the other kernels, then?

Comment: This looks like a very long and specific question for this site. I suggest that you open an issue in [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/issues) and hopefully it will be looked at within too long.

Comment: @EgeRubak Thank you, I did open an [issue](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/issues/77) as you suggested. I am sorry, I am new to this whole asking-a-question-about-code thing. Indeed, I was unsure where to post mine. Thanks again for pointing out where it belongs.  Do you think I should delete the question here? Additionally, should I move [My other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757923/issue-pasing-arguments-to-kernel-functions-through-density-ppp), too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found a bug in the code for `density.ppp` in the case where `at="points"`, `leaveoneout=FALSE`, and `kernel` is not the default. The value of the kernel at distance zero is not evaluated correctly in this case.

The bug will be fixed in the development version of `spatstat` shortly.

Regarding your other questions I'm afraid I don't have time to explain what we are doing with this code. It is still under development (as you can see by the comments `"Experimental code"`) to make it run faster. The legacy code is there so we can check that it is still valid.